# Adjective for 'made of pus' or 'corrupted by pus' or something of something of pus

Tags: single-word-requests

This to be used in a sentence with:

> a somethingish discharge

I like "pustulous discharge" but 'pustulous' is of pustules not of their content.

'Pusy' would be a natural but doesn't look like what it's trying to mean so..

Comment: There’s _purulent_, but that more commonly means ‘leaking pus’, so a scab or wound would be more likely to be purulent than the discharge itself.

Comment: If that's the word you're looking for, maybe vocabulary isn't your biggest problem just now.

Comment: This is wrong but it was funny to me:  pusillanimous

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word **pustulent**, seems exactly what you are looking for, but since no one has suggested it yet, perhaps there is something wrong with it.

> Filled or oozing with pus

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pustulent)

Comment: This is a good alternative to purulent.

Comment: This is good because it contains the word 'pus'. I had previously chosen 'purulent' but the meaning is not as clear as it is with 'pustulent'

Comment: To anyone who actually knows the word, it is. There's nothing ambiguous about "purulent".

Comment: @Beanluc In the context I am using the word - setting a mood -  the sense of the word is as important as its meaning. Pustulent is a strong word, it `spits` pus whereas 'purulent'  feels more like a dismissive, it feels more like a moral judgment of a thing than like a graphic description. The meaning given by the dictionary, or as intended by those who use the word, may be non-judgmental, but to my ear...

Comment: This is clearly what the asker was trying to find with their own guess of "pustulous". But some people might not use this word to describe *discharge*, because discharge isn't "filled with" pus or "oozing with" pus; it **is** pus. It could be argued that *pustulent* would only properly describe a wound or a part of the body. That said, Google does find some instances of the phrase "pustulent discharge", so clearly some people are fine with it.

Comment: @StephenBoston The connection between pus and purulent is initially obscured by the change of s to r, an example of Latin rhotacism. But when you realise that this same shift has found its way into English in other places it isn't so mysterious anymore. Compare justice (from iūstitia from iūs) with jurisprudence (from iūrisprūdentia from iūris (genitive singular of iūs) + prūdēns). See also mouse (which isn't from Latin mūs, but is related to it) and the adjective murine. An example that doesn't show itself in English is Latin flōs 'flower' but English has inherited floral (from flōrālis)

Answer (score 59):

The word you are looking for is **purulent**:

> consisting of, containing, or discharging pus.
>   *"a purulent discharge"*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/purulent)</sub>

It is not an especially common word in general, but it is the medical word for this.

Answer (score 12):

The actual adjective for *pus* is [**pussy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pussy#h3), with a double *s*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : full of or resembling pus
>   // a *pussy* wound

Note that the pronunciation starts off the same as that of *pus* itself—as opposed to the pronunciation of the other senses of the word.

---

Specific context, either through identifying the location or using it alongside another adjective, will also help avoid any confusion (and possibly unfortunate misunderstandings) when it comes to expressing it in written form:

> There is a pussy discharge coming from my arm wound.
>   My cut is producing a yellow and pussy discharge.

Comment: If this is for something written, rather than spoken, you might run into the problem of people initially reading it as the other word with the same spelling, which changes the meaning drastically.

Comment: Many years ago, I put "pussy discharge" on a test for health class in high school and got a "see me after class" note from the teacher, who did not read it as an adjective for "pus".

Comment: @WaterMolecule Without context, it can be ambiguous. However, if you've already established that you're talking about a wound on some identified part the body, then the meaning would be clear. *A pussy wound on my arm*, for instance, or *a pussy discharge from my arm wound*. Or even if its used in combination with another adjective that provides grammatical context: *a yellow and pussy discharge*.

Comment: @JasonBassford as long as you're not talking about a wound caused by an axe, I guess you might get away with it.

Comment: Am I the only person who briefly misread the word "cut" in the last example sentence?

Comment: Never use this word in writing! There is anyway no need for it -- you can use _purulent_ instead. (In speech, it's fine, because the pronunciation disambiguates it.)

Comment: This is certainly not a *wrong* answer, but the asker was clearly trying to avoid this option. I would have left a comment, rather than an answer, to point out the correct spelling.

Comment: this is a mean joke to anyone not familiar with english

Comment: The best solution is to write the entire work in rhyming verse, and put the word "pussy" at the end of a line, following a line ending with "fussy". This is a perfect way to solve the phonetic ambiguity.

Comment: If I were writing it, I’d put puss-y even though the original is perfectly correct and pussy sounding like ‘cat’ in its sense of meaning vagina is more American, however pussy in that sense is well-known in English so er yes tricky when written. Reminds me of the word for ‘saucer’ in Indonesian which sounds very similar to ‘pepek’ which means vagina in Balinese. So all you have to do is ask them to ‘pass me that saucer’ and their eyes curl upwards like crescent moons, as do their mouths, trying to suppress a giggle...

Answer (score 7):

Both ***putrid*** and ***putrescent*** derive from the same root as *pus*.

Per [etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pus), pus is related to the Latin *puter* (rotten) and *putere* (to stink). [Putrid](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=putrid) made its way into English from these same roots in the 15th century in reference to typhus, aka putrid fever. Putrescent was a later addition, coming into English in the 17th century. Both words would carry the sense that the discharge was foul-smelling.

Answer (score 4):

**suppurate**

from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition.
intransitive verb To form or discharge pus.

https://www.wordnik.com/words/suppurate

"a suppurous discharge"

Answer (score 3):

**pus-like** adj.  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155110?redirectedFrom=pus%20like#eid27596434) a derivative of pus; more of a layman's term.

As in:

> 2001   Cats June    Most bacterial infections that I have seen create
>   an effusion of **pus-like** fluid.

Comment: But something that is "pus-like" does not need to be pus, does it?

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing Medical Transcription, I would use what the doctor dictates on that one, or leave a blank as guessing is not good.  Doctor may be describing color, amount of pus. Go with what you are confident. 
Legal document.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what a doctor might say?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is that doctor.

Answer (score -1):

## *Suppurating*

Given so finely Latinate a verb as *suppurate* is for a jumping off point, lots of different possible suffixes could be used for deriving an adjective. But of these, *suppurating* (as in suppurating sores) is the only one that sees much present-day use.

Per the OED, it means:

> Forming, containing, or discharging pus; characterized by suppuration; suppurative. Also in figurative context.

Older choices no longer viable outside a period piece include *supperative, suppurable, suppurant, suppurate, suppurated, suppurant, suppuratory*.

Answer (score -2):

While it doesn't mean the exact same thing, the word '*viscid*' might be a good fit.

> 1a : having an adhesive quality : sticky
>
> b : having a glutinous consistency : viscous

[Merriam- Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viscid)

Comment: The meaning isn't quite right--honey, which is delicious and lovely, has those qualities too--but it does *sound* gross, which might let it work in fiction ("Viscid green mucus dripped from the dragon's nose and sizzled onto the rocks"), if not a medical text.

Comment: @MattKrause - The asker is definitely looking for mood-setting rather than accuracy. (They've since added comments regarding *purulent* versus *pustulent* that make this clear.) We don't have to worry that people will mistakenly think of something pleasant when they see *viscid* in this case, because the full phrase, as expressed in the question, would be "viscid discharge". (And honestly, even when used to describe honey, "thick and sticky" doesn't really sound pleasant to me.)

Comment: Honeyed with a purulent discharge ooh lovely